# MS Access filter form to open report to specific records

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a form, ReportSearch that has multiple comboboxes and textboxes that will allow the user to narrow down the results shown on the report. Not all fields would have to be used in the search.

On click the following code will ask for the parameter value to be entered for the specific IDs used. If I just click OK without entering anything in the MsgBox the report will be opened with no records.

```
Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long

Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yy\#"

If Not IsNull(Me.cboSearchJob) Then
   strWhere = strWhere & "(Job.id = " & Me.cboSearchJob & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cboSearchEmployee) Then
   strWhere = strWhere & "(Employee.ID = " & Me.cboSearchEmployee & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cboSearchService) Then
   strWhere = strWhere & "(Service.ID = " & Me.cboSearchService & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.tboStartDate) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "(DateWorked >= " & Format(Me.tboStartDate, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.tboEndDate) Then
   strWhere = strWhere & "(DateWorked < " & Format(Me.tboEndDate + 1, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If

lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then
   MsgBox "No Results", vbInformation, "No Search Available."
Else
    strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)

    DoCmd.OpenReport "JobReport", acViewPreview
    Reports!JobReport.Filter = strWhere
    Reports!JobReport.FilterOn = True

   End If


End Sub
```

For the report I'm using

```
  SELECT [Employees].[FirstName] & " " & [Employees].[LastName] AS EmployeeName, Jobs.JobName, Equipment.Model, Service.Service, Labor.Labor, EmployeeWorkLog.LaborHours, EmployeeWorkLog.EquipmentHours, EmployeeWorkLog.Notes, EmployeeWorkLog.DateWorked, Service.ID
FROM Service RIGHT JOIN (Labor RIGHT JOIN (Jobs RIGHT JOIN (Equipment RIGHT JOIN (Employees RIGHT JOIN EmployeeWorkLog ON Employees.ID = EmployeeWorkLog.EmployeeID) ON Equipment.ID = EmployeeWorkLog.EquipmentID) ON Jobs.ID = EmployeeWorkLog.JobID) ON Labor.ID = EmployeeWorkLog.LaborID) ON Service.ID = EmployeeWorkLog.ServiceID
ORDER BY [Employees].[FirstName] & " " & [Employees].[LastName];
```

At this point I'm at a complete loss.

Obviously there is something that I'm missing here. Let me know in what way I need to modify this code to get it to open my report JobReport filtered based on my form ReportSearch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A report isn't dynamic like a form, you can't filter it after it has been opened. When a report is opened in print preview, it reads its data, does the layout and formatting, then it's completely static.

To open a report with filtered data, use the `WhereCondition` parameter of `DoCmd.OpenReport`:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "JobReport", acViewPreview, WhereCondition:=strWhere
```

Comment: You're right that was missing. Now I'm receiving the error 3075 "Missing ),], or item in query expression '(Service.ID = 3.    I'm using

Comment: <Blink>  If Not IsNull(Me.cboSearchService) Then
        strWhere = "(Service.ID= " & Me.cboSearchService & ")AND "
    End If   </Blink>

Comment: @Stephenson: your code in the comment misses a blank here: `)AND `, but in the question it's correct. Removing the last 5 chars will remove the closing ) if the blank is missing.

Comment: That worked great. All my comboxes will work to filter the report, but my date textboxes do nothing. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Stephenson: you probably need `"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"` instead of `"\#mm\/dd\/yy\#"` (4-digit year). -- The original question has been answered, please accept the answer to mark the question as solved.